# Javascript to redirect page

Tags: javascript, window.location

I am trying to build a page where I open a projector page, and then send links from my website to that projector page.

I have managed to get it to show the projector page and load the links, but when I refresh or change the parent URL, the projector page is no longer responsive. I believe this is because it is taking my variable name of "projector" and simply giving it a "child" like alias and when I change the parent page, it looses this link.

Is there a better way of accomplishing this where when the parent changes, it keeps the link to the child "Projector" page?

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var projector;
function openProjector()
{
    projector=window.open('','Dwenty Projector','width=800,height=800');
    projector.document.write("<p>This window's name is: " + projector.name + "</p>");
}

<!--
function changeWindow(url){
    window.projector.location=url
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" value="[Open|Refresh] Page Projector" onclick="openProjector()" />

<p align="left"><a href="javascript:changeWindow('http://www.google.com')">Google.com</a></p>
<p align="left"><a href="javascript:changeWindow('http://www.sourceforge.net')">Source Forge.net</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `target` property of `a` tag to point to your projector window.

```
<p align="left"><a href="http://www.google.com" target="Dwenty Projector">Google.com</a>   </p>
<p align="left"><a href="http://www.sourceforge.net" target="Dwenty Projector">Source Forge.net</a></p>
```

Comment: The target property of the <a> tag didn't help. Upon reload of the page it looses connection to the Dwenty Projector.